# spring boot hibernate SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to fetch specific fields of an entity via spring data jpa and dto peojection.

Person class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity(name = "SKU")
@DynamicUpdate
@OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.DIRTY)
public class Sku extends BaseCqrsEntity {
    private Long sellerId;
    private String gtin;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private SkuState state;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private VariantState variantState;
    private String brand;
    
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = VariantImage.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "SKU_VARIANT_IMAGES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SKU_ID"))
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @BatchSize(size = 1000)
    private List<VariantImage> variantImages = new ArrayList<>();

    //OTHER ATTRIBUTES
 }
```

PersonImage class:

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class VariantImage implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7449583602767726061L;

    private Long id;

    private Integer position;

    private String relativePath;
}
```

JPA repository class:

```
@Query(" select new SkuFeedProjection(s.productId, s.variantId, s.categoryId, s.sellerId, s.gtin, s.brand, s.unitPrice, s.discountValue, s.discountType, s.saleStartDate, s.saleEndDate, s.variantTitle, s.currencyId, s.variantImages, s.discountStartDate, s.discountEndDate) from SKU s where s.variantState = :variantState and s.state = :skuState")
    Page<SkuFeedProjection> pageAllByVariantStateAndState(@Param("variantState") VariantState variantState,
                                                          @Param("skuState") SkuState skuState,
                                                          Pageable pageable);
}
```

Exception log:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2322)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2075)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1454)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 131 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:747)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:904)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1082)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3822)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 163 more

Caused by: Error : 936, Position : 408, Sql = select sku0_.product_id as col_0_0_, sku0_.variant_id as col_1_0_, sku0_.category_id as col_2_0_, sku0_.seller_id as col_3_0_, sku0_.gtin as col_4_0_, sku0_.brand as col_5_0_, sku0_.unit_price as col_6_0_, sku0_.discount_value as col_7_0_, sku0_.discount_type as col_8_0_, sku0_.sale_start_date as col_9_0_, sku0_.sale_end_date as col_10_0_, sku0_.variant_title as col_11_0_, sku0_.currency_id as col_12_0_, . as col_13_0_, sku0_.discount_start_date as col_14_0_, sku0_.discount_end_date as col_15_0_ from my_schema.sku sku0_ inner join my_schema.sku_variant_images variantima1_ on sku0_.id=variantima1_.sku_id where sku0_.variant_state=:1  and sku0_.state=:2  fetch first :3  rows only, 

OriginalSql = select sku0_.product_id as col_0_0_, sku0_.variant_id as col_1_0_, sku0_.category_id as col_2_0_, sku0_.seller_id as col_3_0_, sku0_.gtin as col_4_0_, sku0_.brand as col_5_0_, sku0_.unit_price as col_6_0_, sku0_.discount_value as col_7_0_, sku0_.discount_type as col_8_0_, sku0_.sale_start_date as col_9_0_, sku0_.sale_end_date as col_10_0_, sku0_.variant_title as col_11_0_, sku0_.currency_id as col_12_0_, . as col_13_0_, sku0_.discount_start_date as col_14_0_, sku0_.discount_end_date as col_15_0_ from my_schema.sku sku0_ inner join my_schema.sku_variant_images variantima1_ on sku0_.id=variantima1_.sku_id where sku0_.variant_state=? and sku0_.state=? fetch first ? rows only, Error Msg = ORA-00936: missing expression
```

whenever repository method is called. I am getting **org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet.**

This is because, I guess Hibernate does not handle embedded collections (@ElementCollection) well in JPQL when using them in a projection. Could I hear your suggestions. How can I get rid of this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to execute the sql generated at the Caused by line in the database and see what error it gives.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong class in your Native Query:

```
from SKU
```

Native Queries are case sensitive, if you want to select from your entity you should change it to:

```
from Sku
```